# How to execute a user defined JavaScript function using executeScript method of Selenium Java web driver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

This is my code so far to execute function using Selenium:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
script="startDialog('arg1','arg2');";    
js.executeScript(script);
```

Javascript function to be executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var Btn = document.getElementById("btnid");  
    Btn.onclick = function() {  
    startDialog("arg1", "arg2");  
   };  
});
```

Unable to execute `startDialog` function using `executeScript` function of Selenium Java web driver.

Comment: web driver exception undefined is not a function.

Comment: the exception says startDialog is not defined and hence needs to be defined first. JavaScriptExecutor will work well once it finds the function.

Answer (score 0):

Where is startDialog defined? The function you refer to isnt named and only calls startDialog.

Ofter the exception is correct. The function you are trying to call is undefined.

Comment: startDialog is defined in js file

Answer (score 0):

The script has to be the exact java script, not a function name. Try to assign the body of the function for script variable and then executing it.
Like this -

```
script="$(document).ready(function() {" +     
"var Btn = document.getElementById('btnid');"+  
"Btn.onclick = function() {" +
"startDialog('arg1', 'arg2');};});"
```